# wp_editor not modify html tags of initial content

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, customization

How can i set the tinyMCE editor in wp_editor to not modify/replace the html tags of the initial content ?

I'm loading html content with  tags (i know that they are deprecated but i need  them) and the tinyMCE editor is replacing them.

I tried several things but with no success. I'm getting a little frustrated. I need help.

What i need is that the editor do not change the loaded html content.

Sorry for my bad english! It's not my native language.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use this free plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Comment: Please explain **how** this plugin could solve the OP's problem